# Buttons inside datatables cell not sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have buttons inside datatables cells:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-modal3" data-remote="../api/?type=list-of-ranged&amp;pid=4694124&">2</button>
```

Problem is that sorting is not working. If I define :

```
{"title":"Ranged", "data":"Ranged", "type":"num-html"},
```

I get some funny sorting , like : 2,3,1,1,2,1

If I do not define anything there, it detects it as html and again I get some funny sorting.

I read about the data-sort and data-order property which I have added as bellow :

```
<button data-sort="8" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-modal3" data-remote="../api/?type=list-of-ranged&amp;pid=4694124&">2</button>
```

but still get the same problem.
How do I properly sort this column?

Note: I am generating the buttons in some other part of the code so I cannot touch the th tag. code is generated from php and is consumed via ajax in the datatable as bellow :

```
$aaData[$storeIndex]['Ranged'] = '<button data-sort="'.$ranged_v.'" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remote-modal1" data-remote="'.$rangedurl.'">'.$ranged_v.'</a>';
```

Comment: The problem is that `data-order` work with the `td` element, you set data-attributes in your button, show your initializacion of DataTable to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the [data-attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) are specified in `td` element, if you not have access to `td` element, you can use [fnRowCallback](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback) to find the `data-sort` in your button and add to `td`, (***Remember specified the index of td***):

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var nOrder = $('td:eq(0)', nRow).find("button").data("sort");
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr("data-sort",nOrder);
}
```

**Result**: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/75/

**UPDATE** : When you specified the column type `num-html`, you should import the [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/num-html):

```
{
    "title":"Ranged", 
    "data":"Ranged", 
    "type":"num-html"
}
```

Import the plugi-in in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/num-html.js"></script>
```

**Result Update:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/suo68emm/1/

Comment: Hi, this jsfiddle is exactly my problem, but still will not work. I forked your fiddle and changed the numbers from 1,2,3,4 to 1,100,110,1000 and looks like they still sort alphebatically and not numerically.  https://jsfiddle.net/suo68emm/

Comment: Unbelievable! Thank you, best answer ever :)